# Image Stream in ImageReader from Camera2 API

Tags: opencv, android-camera2

I want to capture Images as a sequential stream in OnImageAvailableListener of the ImageReader.

My Aim is to process these images in a background thread.

In the basic camera2 example this ImageAvailable Listener is called only once when I take a picture by clicking a button.

I need to get this OnImageAvailable called in real time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ImageReader Surface into the repeating preview request targets as well, instead of just to the still image capture.

You likely also want to use a YUV_420_888 format instead of JPEG, depending on your use case.

Comment: when I add ImagerReader's surface as second target it slows down FPS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579859/camera2-set-preview-view-and-get-preview-callbacks