# Camera2 set preview (View) and get preview callbacks

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to get preview from Camera2 and also byte[] callback for processing frames

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
        ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR,1);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
```

.

```
SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
assert texture != null;

// We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

// This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

// We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
mPreviewRequestBuilder
        = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
// also for preview callbacks
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
```

But when I add second target (ImageReader's surface) fps get very bad 10-15 instead of 30

With Legacy Camera API it was working ok

**byte[] frames callback**

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

}
```

**preview**

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getSurfaceHolder());
```

It didn't effect FPS quality with legacy Camera API

So how to get they same result with Camera2?

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting full-resolution RAW frames; those aren't guaranteed to be available at 30fps (because they tend to be large).  You can check their max frame rate via [StreamConfigurationMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputMinFrameDuration(int,%20android.util.Size)) queries.

If you want to match the old API behavior, you want to set the ImageReader resolution to match your preview resolution, and the format to YUV_420_888.
On higher-end devices, you can probably set the resolution to maximum with YUV_420_888, or even use RAW output, but that's going to be device specific (look for devices that support the [BURST_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BURST_CAPTURE) capability)

Comment: I was trying to set YUV_420_888 as well, but still some issues, also intresting that I set 1920x1080 for ImageReader but I get 1440x1080 in mOnImageAvailableListener, only surface preview of textureview shows 1920x1080 correctly